# how to block future date and time in angular bootstrap datepicker

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datepicker

How to block future date and time in angular bootstrap datepicker. I have found some example but it is block till before 4 hours

What exactly I want is to block till current hour and current minute

Is it possible to do that?

```
$scope.beforeRender = function($dates) {
  /* disable future dates */
  for (var i = 0; i < $dates.length; i++) {
    if (new Date().getTime() < $dates[i].utcDateValue) {
      $dates[i].selectable = false;
    }
  }
};
```

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <div class="input-group">
        <div class="form-control" id="selected_date">
            {{ formData.dateInput | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' }}
        </div>
          <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <datetimepicker data-ng-model="formData.dateInput"       
        data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown2' " />
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you write your html code? are you using uib-datepicker-popup tag ?

Answer (score 0):

Use end date option

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-date-end-date="0d">
```

http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/options.html#enddate

Comment: it is not working and the plugin is angular bootstrap datepicker and posted my html also

Comment: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Functions/#minmaxdate